# How to apply css for min-width and print?

Tags: css, media-queries

I would like to apply a CSS media query to a certain screen size AND print media type.

Is it possible to do it with something like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and print {...}
```

Comment: Of course after I posted this I think I figured it out... `@media print, (min-width: 768px){..}`

Comment: Ray, that's correct. You should answer your own question. Just a tip, in this case is not "AND" but "OR"... "AND" has another meaning, that is if both conditions were met.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to apply css to

> screen size AND print media type

is

```
@media print and (min-width: 768px) { }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjtz9jaq/1/

If you don't put the `and` then you get results that affect screen as well demonstrated here

http://jsfiddle.net/kjtz9jaq/

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is: `@media print, (min-width: 768px){..}`

Comment from LcSalazar:

> Just a tip, in this case is not "AND" but "OR"... "AND" has another
>   meaning, that is if both conditions were met.